# Linq ToLookUp too slow

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

How can I streamline the LookUp command below?

I have this context:

```
var lookup = query.ToLookup(
                i => new { PaisId = i.PaisId, EmpresaId = i.EmpresaId, Codigo = i.Codigo, Nome = i.Nome, OrigemId = i.OrigemId },
                v => new HierarquiaUsuarioSimplesDto { PapelId = v.PapelId, HierarquiaPapelId = v.HierarquiaPapelId, Usuario = new HierarquiaUsuarioDto { Id = v.UsuarioId, Nome = v.UsuarioNome, Matricula = v.UsuarioMatricula, GrupoCargo = v.UsuarioGrupoCargo, GrupoCargoNome = v.GrupoCargoNome } }
            );

        var item = query.FirstOrDefault();

        return new HierarquiaDto
        {
            PaisId = item.PaisId,
            EmpresaId = item.EmpresaId,
            Codigo = item.Codigo,
            Nome = item.Nome,
            OrigemId = item.OrigemId,
            IsPendente = item.IsPendente,
            Usuarios = lookup.FirstOrDefault().ToList()
        };´
```

The `query.ToLookup` command is very slow because it returns a lot of data.

Comment: What does it mean to only take the first value of a lookup like you do currently? It could be anything, in perhaps any order. Maybe you don't really need a lookup but a where+select that filters those items by some common value (The values that form the the key of your current "first" lookup group) and then projects to your item-type

Comment: This query is very strange. Can you describe what you're trying to do here? It is legal to use an anonymous type as a key, but it is unusual; why are you doing that?  Why are you getting the first item from the lookup? Lookups are not constructed to have a particular ordering. I don't think the problem is that it is too slow; I think the problem is that it is the wrong tool for whatever job it is that you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you're using ToLookUp() incorrectly.  ToLookup is used to build a dictionary of lists.  The first parameter is used to create the key for each list entered into the dictionary.

To me, the code you've written looks like nothing you would normally do with ToLookUp()

Comment: I am trying to create a list of type HierarchyDto, in this object I have another called HierarchyUsuarioSimplesDto and inside this I have another one that is called User HierarchyD, I did not do this code I am just trying to improve it.
Here is the query I do before:

Comment: public HierarquiaDto Selecionar(int id)
        { var query = (from p in Context.PapelContratos join g in Context.GruposCargo on new { a=p.UsuarioGrupoCargo, b=p.EmpresaId }  equals new { a=g.Sigla, b=g.EmpresaId } into pg
from g in pg.DefaultIfEmpty()
where p.OrigemId == id
select new{p.PaisId,p.EmpresaId,p.Codigo,p.Nome,p.PapelId,OrigemId = p.OrigemId.Value,p.IsPendente,p.HierarquiaPapelId,p.UsuarioId,p.UsuarioNome,p.UsuarioGrupoCargo,p.UsuarioMatricula,GrupoCargoNome = g.Nome});

Comment: I need all the users that belong to that PaisId, CompanyId, Code, Name and OriginId.

Comment: @CyroBergonzi Hey Cyro, it would really be best if you take these comments and post a new question.  Stackoverflow emphasizes the importance of clear, high quality questions that people can understand and quickly answer.  You can either delete this question or leave it.  If you leave it, I recommend accepting the answer, since the problem has been determined to be different from what your question put forth.  As you can see from having to post several comments in a row, Stackoverflow is different from a forum.  It's less about conversations and more about clear questions with clear answers.

Comment: @CyroBergonzi I recommend reading this if you haven't:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I believe (from the other question) that `ToLookup` is being used to (poorly) emulate `GroupBy` in this case. Poorly, and not guaranteed to be correct.